# StepArgumentTransformation using multiple parameters

Tags: c#, .net, specflow

I am using Specflow for Test Automation. I have found out about the useful StepArgumentTransformation binding.

When there are multiple input parameters is there a way to only transform one of the input parameters? Take the following as an example:

```cs
[StepArgumentTransformation(@"button '(.*)' is '(.*)'")]
public bool ThenButtonIsTransformation(string buttonName, string status)
{
     // Do some work here
}
```

I want to be able to return a boolean true or false based on the value of status. I don't care about the buttonName value.

So in summary, I want both input parameters coming into the step function but I don't want to have to worry about returning a complex object from the transformation method in order to store both input parameters.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. just ignore any inputs you don't want... you are free to return whatever you want from your step argument transformation

Comment: Hi sam. Maybe I have it wrong but from the way I was thinking the object returned feeds into the actual step function as an input?

Comment: Maybe you could include more code to illustrate the actual issue you have and what exactly is not working the way you expect? I'm finding it difficult to understand what your problem actually is.

Answer (score -1):

In feature file:

```
Scenario: stackoverflow usecase
        Given button green is true
```

In step definition:

```
[Given(@"button (.*) (is .*)")]
        public void ThenButtonIsTransformation(string buttonColor, bool status)
        {
            string color = buttonColor;
            bool value = status;
            Console.Write("Button color is: {0} and value is: {1}", color, value);
        }


[StepArgumentTransformation(@"is (\w+)")]
        public bool ProduceBoolValue(string status)
        {
            if (status.ToLower().Equals("true"))
                return true;
            if (status.ToLower().Equals("false"))
                return false;
            return false;
        }
```